# Wrong Latitude/longitude received in Android Emulator on Mac

Tags: android, macos, ddms

Ok, this is a really weird one.

I'm sending Latitude/Longitude to Emulator running my App and its getting the wrong Coordinates !!! Everything I send (either via DDMS using GPX file, DDMS Manual, or telnet and using geo fix command), gets received, but when I print the latitude/longitude points received by the app, there are off by just a little bit (well a few hundred yards to where I was aiming for).

Discovered this because I've always tested my app on a PC, but recently purchased a Mac. So I'm going through my standard tests, using the GPX file with lat/long points that I always used on the PC, and the app is showing the wrong location.

Example: 
I send this: 
geo fix geo fix -72.74 41.74
And in my app, onLocationChanged, location.toString() says this:
Location[mProvider=gps,mTime=1287892837000,mLatitude=**41.74016776666667**,mLongitude=**-72.74533443333333**,mHasAltitude=false,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=false,mAccuracy=0.0,mExtras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=4]]

I mean what the heck?? Tested with Google Maps also, and if I select myLocation, it goes to the same wacky coordinates instead of the actual ones I sent.

Looks like some weird math or conversion issue, since the numbers are close, but not exact.

**Again, this all works fine on the PC,** meaning, on the PC it gets the exact coordinates that I send. For the Emulator I created an avd using AVD manager, WVGA854, Google API Level 8.

Running on new MacBook pro, and new Eclipse Helios install and new install of Android SDK.

Comment: +1 I'm having the same problem on PC. See [Emulator receives wrong GPS coordinates when playing KML in DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298019/emulator-receives-wrong-gps-coordinates-when-playing-kml-in-ddms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the bug in DDMS . 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11264